# Java what does a thread do when it's done running?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

In a game I'm making I use many instances of a thread, and it does not keep track of them.

```
clientThread cT = new clientThread(socket);
new Thread(cT).start();
```

What I need to know is that when an instance of the tread has finished(all the loops have been completed and it is no longer being used), just like an instance of a method, is it discarded? Or do I need to use a special piece of code to discard it?

Comment: You could try not discarding them at all.  There are, I believe, while loops in java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The thread is a normal object, which will be garbage collected like any other object. In the case of a thread object, it becomes eligible for collection when the thread exits.

Answer (score 4):

It will be discarded as soon as `run()` completed. You don't need to add any special piece of code to release .

Note: Discarded doesn't mean, it's gone from memory (but it won't run further). It may be GCed when next GC collection runs.

Comment: Hmmm, discarded as soon as `run()` is complete is a bit overreaching. It will cease to run, but the GC in Java is not greedy, it will only run when it deems necessary.

Comment: And even then, the `Thread` (or `Runnable`, or `Callable`) won't be GC'ed if someone else is holding a reference to it. It's just like any other object in that sense.

Comment: @yshavit: Any object can't be GCed unless they are NOT reachable. Can you provide an example/case which may hold the thread even after it's completion?

Comment: @thinksteep Easy. `final static Thread myThreadRef = whatever(); static { myThreadRef.start(); }` Even after the thread finishes, the `Thread` object will stay until the class that defines `myThreadRef` is unloaded.

Comment: @yshavit It won't be GCed if anything else is holding a *non-weak* reference to it ;)

Comment: @TheZ Ha, fair enough! What I was really trying to get across is that after `run()` completes, a `Thread` is just like any other object in terms of GC.

Answer (score 2):

If the garbage collector gets to it it will be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

The other friends answered exactly what you ask. One comment only.

> I'm making I use many instances of a thread, and it does not keep
>   track of them.

Do NOT do this: `new Thread(cT).start();` I.e. start spawning threads.
Read about thread pools and [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: +1 but, IME, you're wasting your time.  Somewhere out there is a Uni course or WebPage that says 'continually creating threads, waiting with Join() and then letting the thread terminate' is actually a good idea.  Until the course/site author is assassinated for the good of the whole world, your efforts are wasted <g>.  I would gladly pull the trigger myself.